# How to show images of the gallery on click of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam creating a gallery tab for a webpage which will show three thumbnails intially. My achievement is to show the rest of the thumbnails on click of a class called `show-all`. For this I am animating my gallery height to show the content which is hidden. Everything goes well according to the function. But the problem which Iam facing here is when I about to make `hide` thumbnails which exceed the `height` of the gallery using `overflow:hidden` still I can see some parts of my second row thumbnails. I just want to make them hide. Below is my code block

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
     <h3>Photos</h3>
 <a class="see-all" href="javascript:void(0)">See All</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.see-all').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.gallery').animate({height: $(".gallery").get(0).scrollHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/e0Ldautb/2/)**

**NOTE**: Cannot change my height of the gallery since my image size are not as same as always.

Comment: If you don't want to see the second row just modify the css and let the gallery height to be 260px.

Comment: Iam aware of it already but i need it to more specific like when the first row is visible the rest should be get `display:none` or `visiblity:hidden` something like that this is because the height of the image can be vary.

Comment: Oh, I see your problem, you should specify this is the question. I'll try to write a solution for your problem in jsfiddle. :)

Comment: cannot place each row of thumbanails in wrapper. I need all my div to be placed in a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on gallery height manipulation, you can just choose to show the first 3 images and hide the rest... This way you're not stuck with maintaining image heights and such.

When you click `see all`, it will reveal the rest.

JS BIN: http://jsbin.com/qoliqukoye/1/edit?html,js,output

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var x = 0;
            $('.row').children().each(function () {
                if (x >= 3) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                x++;
            });
            $(".see-all").click(function(){
                $('.row').children().fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
```

[image]

Comment: I need animate rest on appearing not just fade in or fade out

Comment: @Benjamin Can you elaborate what you mean on "I need animate rest on appearing"?

Comment: @Benjamin If this helps you or answers your question can you accept?

Comment: just check the answer of @sticksu I need that kinda animation

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/e0Ldautb/3/) I have a problem in `min-view` do you have any idea how do i fix that

Answer (score 1):

So you can do it like this: add a class on the first 3 elements, the ones that are visible and hide all the thumbnails except for those.
Then the js should look like this:

```
$('.see-all').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.gallery').animate({height:'810px'});
  $('.thumbnail').show();
});
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wvzyzLo1/1/

Comment: thats something cool thinking i will give you a upvote for this and let me wait for some more simplest answer. Anyways thanks for the help. I owe you. :)

Comment: Dude need another favor from you with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/wvzyzLo1/2/) im wrong somewhere can you point me out

Comment: You need to run the hide function when the animation is completed. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/7mdev50m/3/

Comment: I need to animate `height` to `auto` do you any idea how do i do that